# Python3 sort a list based on another list when the lists are uneven in length

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have two lists:

```
list1 = ["a","e","d","c","f","g"]
list2 = ["a","c","d","f"]
```

In this the `list1` cannot be sorted and should be retained as is.  I am trying to sort the `list2` exactly in the same order as `list1` and get the `missing values` from `list1` that exists between the first and last value of `list2`.

For example, if I sort `list2` as according to `list1`using the following code,

```
list2 = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(list1,list2))]
```

I get the following index based sorted list:

```
list2 = ['a', 'f', 'd', 'c']
```

However the desired output is

```
list2 = ['a','d','c','f']
```

How can I sort the list2 according to the list1 taking the literal sequence of elements and not the index position based sorting.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the most efficient, and it doesn't cope with duplicates, but the following list comprehension should do what you want:

```
list1 = ["a","e","d","c","f","g"]
list2 = ["a","c","d","f"]
print([x for x in list1 if x in list2])
['a', 'd', 'c', 'f']
```

It walks `list1`, using the item if it is found in `list2`.

Comment: many thanks.....I do not have duplicates in either of the lists...accepting your answer